# Load view from XIB as a subview of a scrollview

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, scrollview, xib

I'm still a SO and Swift newbie, so please, be patient and feel free to skip this question   :-)

In the body of a `XIB`'s `awakeFromNib`, I want to load some views as subviews of a `UIScrollView` (basically, the `XIB` contains a scrollview, a label and a button).

The scrollview perfectly works if in a loop I load views I create on the fly, eg.

```
 let customView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 300, height: 150))
 customView.frame = CGRect(x: i*300 , y: 0, width: 300, height: 150)
 customView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
 scrollView.addSubview(customView)
```

But I have a different goal.

In another `XIB` I have an image view and a stackview with some labels. This `XIB` is connected in the storyboard to a class `SingleEvent` that extends `UIView`.

I want to do the following:

1. use the `XIB` as a sort of "blueprint" and load the same view multiple times in my scrollview;
2. pass to any instance some data;

Is this possible?

I tried to load the content of the XIB this way:

```
 let customView = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("SingleEvent", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as? SingleEvent
```

and this way:

```
let customView = SingleEvent()
```

The first one makes the app crash, while the second causes no issue, but I can't see any effect (it doesn't load anything).

The content of my latest `SingleEvent` is the following:

```
 import UIKit

    class SingleEvent: UIView {

        @IBOutlet weak var label:UILabel!
        @IBOutlet weak var imageView:UIImageView!

        override init(frame: CGRect) {
            super.init(frame: frame)

            loadViewFromNib()
        }

        required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
            super.init(coder: aDecoder)

            loadViewFromNib()
        }

        func loadViewFromNib() -> UIView {
            let myView = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("SingleEvent", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! UIView
            return myView
        }
    }
```

Thanks in advance, any help is appreciated  :-)

Comment: Hi! You'r second way call common init but your loadViewFromNib() function called inside init(frame: CGRect), so try init your view like this: 
let customView = SingleEvent(frame: someFrame)

Comment: @Ildar.Z: it doesn't work

Comment: added answer to make it more clear

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a number of approaches to loading custom views (classes) from xibs. You may find this method a bit easier.

First, create your xib like this:

[image]

Note that the Class of `File's Owner` is the default (`NSObject`).

Instead, assign your custom class to the "root" view in your xib:

[image]

Now, our entire custom view class looks like this:

```
class SingleEvent: UIView {

    @IBOutlet var topLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var middleLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var bottomLabel: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet var imageView: UIImageView!

}
```

And, instead of putting `loadNibNamed(...)` inside our custom class, we create a `UIView` extension:

```
extension UIView {
    class func fromNib<T: UIView>() -> T {
        return Bundle.main.loadNibNamed(String(describing: T.self), owner: nil, options: nil)![0] as! T
    }
}
```

To load and use our custom class, we can do this:

```
class FromXIBViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // create an instance of SingleEvent from its xib/nib
        let v = UIView.fromNib() as SingleEvent

        // we're going to use auto-layout & constraints
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        // set the text of the labels
        v.topLabel?.text    = "Top Label"
        v.middleLabel?.text = "Middle Label"
        v.bottomLabel?.text = "Bottom Label"

        // set the image
        v.imageView.image = UIImage(named: "myImage")

        // add the SingleEvent view
        view.addSubview(v)

        // constrain it 200 x 200, centered X & Y
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            v.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200.0),
            v.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200.0),
            v.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
            v.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor),
            ])

    }

}
```

With a result of:

[image]

And... here is an example of loading 10 instances of `SingleEvent` view and adding them to a vertical scroll view:

```
class FromXIBViewController: UIViewController {

    var theScrollView: UIScrollView = {
        let v = UIScrollView()
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        v.backgroundColor = .cyan
        return v
    }()

    var theStackView: UIStackView = {
        let v = UIStackView()
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        v.axis = .vertical
        v.alignment = .fill
        v.distribution = .fill
        v.spacing = 20.0
        return v
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // add the scroll view to the view
        view.addSubview(theScrollView)

        // constrain it 40-pts on each side
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            theScrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 40.0),
            theScrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: -40.0),
            theScrollView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor, constant: 40.0),
            theScrollView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor, constant: -40.0),
            ])

        // add a stack view to the scroll view
        theScrollView.addSubview(theStackView)

        // constrain it 20-pts on each side
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            theStackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: theScrollView.topAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            theStackView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: theScrollView.bottomAnchor, constant: -20.0),
            theStackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: theScrollView.leadingAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            theStackView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: theScrollView.trailingAnchor, constant: -20.0),

            // stackView width = scrollView width -40 (20-pts padding on left & right
            theStackView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: theScrollView.widthAnchor, constant: -40.0),
            ])


        for i in 0..<10 {

            // create an instance of SingleEvent from its xib/nib
            let v = UIView.fromNib() as SingleEvent

            // we're going to use auto-layout & constraints
            v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

            // set the text of the labels
            v.topLabel?.text    = "Top Label: \(i)"
            v.middleLabel?.text = "Middle Label: \(i)"
            v.bottomLabel?.text = "Bottom Label: \(i)"

            // set the image (assuming we have images named myImage0 thru myImage9
            v.imageView.image = UIImage(named: "myImage\(i)")

            theStackView.addArrangedSubview(v)

        }

    }

}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: First of all, thanks for your kind reply. My case is a little different. In the last portion of your code, I see you load SingleEvents from a UIViewController. I'm not actually in a viewcontroller: I'm in a UIView loaded from an awakeFromNib that embeds a scrollView. I can't describe the project in detail, it is fairly complex and I'm only refactoring part of it (I should turn a "dumb" tooltip to a "smart" one). Now I'm searching for a way to pass a dictionary to this scrollview before any subview is loaded

Comment: It doesn't matter if you're instantiating your custom views from a `UIViewController` or from some other custom `UIView`. No difference.

Comment: Ok, I just wanted to say something you probably just knew before replying: that is, there's always a context   :-)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I see. The problem probably in fact that loadViewFromNib function return UIView from xib, but you doesn't use it any way.
Let's try this way:
1) Make your loadViewFromNib function static

```
    // Return our SingleEvent instance here  
    static func loadViewFromNib() -> SingleEvent {
            let myView = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("SingleEvent", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! SingleEvent
            return myView
        }
```

2) Remove all inits in SingleEvent class

3) Init it in needed place like this:

```
let customView = SingleView.loadViewFromNib()
```

To pass data inside view you can create new function in SingleView class:

```
func configureView(with dataModel:DataModel) {
   //Set data to IBOutlets here
}
```

And use it from outside like this:

```
let customView = SingleView.loadViewFromNib()
let dataModel = DataModel()
customView.configureView(with: dataModel)
```

Comment: Ok, but how do I pass data to any single view?

Comment: @Planemo I updated answer please check it! Hope it's help!

Comment: I'm about to try your solution but I must say I see an issue I had just seen before: I only get one subview loaded (I can scroll right-to-left, but after the first subview I see no other instance)

Comment: I think configureView can't be used this way because with loadViewFromNib you are returning a view from a static function, not from an instance: so, how do I reference the outlets? I suppose the only place is the loadViewFromNib

Comment: @Planemo Sorry, I updated answer. Static function return an instance of SingleEvent from Bundle it's a common way to do it and should work properly. Please be sure that every instance of  SingleView must have it's own frame position inside root view (in your case inside scroll view). Is it correct for you?

Comment: This simply crashes   :-(

Comment: @Planemo hmm... Are your Xib file named "SingleEvent" and root UIView inside it has class SingleEvent?

Comment: Of course, the XIB, the File Owner and the main view are "SingleEvent"

Comment: (just a note) I found what caused the subviews to disappear: it was `customView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false`