# How to resize ViewController root view automatically to fit its content?

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller, ios-autolayout

When creating a new `UIViewController` the root view within the corresponding XIB file can be set to any **fixed** height. However, the root view should automatically fit its content. How can this be done?

- Create a new XIB file:
- Add a new subview to the root view and give it some fixed width and height.
- Add a leading constraint to the subview to define the X position
- Add a top constraint to the subview to define the Y positon
- Add a bottom constraint to the subview to define the content height (`top + subview height + bottom`)
- Until now everything is fine because `top + subview height + bottom` equals the height of the root view.
- If the top or bottom constraint is set to another value I would expect that the root view is resized to match its content. However, IB complains about conflicting constraints instead.

**How can this be solved?**

Of course in most cases the size of the root view is not defined by its content but by the screen, modal view, etc. the ViewController is displayed in.

**However, I would like to show the ViewController as content of a `ScrollView` within another ViewController.** In this case the `ContentViewController` should match its content and the ScrollView would make sure that the complete content is reachable.

**Can this be solved within IB without manipulating the constraints in code?**

Comment: Here is an example of loading xib views into a scroll view. You may find it helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54634586/6257435

Answer (score 0):

After some more trial and error an found a working solution: **Simply do not use the root view** :-)

I added another view at root level to the XIB file and moved the root view into it, making the root view a subview of the new view. As long as the VCs `view` outlet still points to the root view (which isn't at root level anymore) this works fine.

The root view can still be accessed by `theViewController.view`. Since it is not placed at root level it is no problem to size it by its content.

While this works fine it is quite hacky. Is there any cleaner solution which does not require a dummy wrapper view?